# How to solve Incompatibility and ambiguous issue during data migration from Magento 1.9.3.2 to Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

I am trying to migrate data from Magento 1.9.3.2 to Magento 2.1.5

I am using Data Migration Tool by Magento => http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool.html

When I start migrating using command: bin/magento migrate:data [-r|--reset] {}, I receive the following error:

```
2017-04-09 19:45:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check]
[step: Data Integrity Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check]
[step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document:
eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=222
cannot contain empty field value
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document:
eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=223
cannot contain empty field value
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document:
eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=224
cannot contain empty field value
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document:
eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=225
cannot contain empty field value
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map
Step]: started
45% [============>---------------] Remaining Time: 4 secs
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][ERROR]: Document has ambiguous configuration:
sales_flat_quote_item
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url
Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log
Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier
Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-04-09 19:45:19][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec

[Migration\Exception]
Integrity Check failed
migrate:data [-r|--reset] config
```

I tried a lot but unable to find a proper solution. Please someone help to solve this error. Which xml file do I need to edit and what do I need to write exactly to solve this issue? Please seeking help from expert. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message points to values for attribute_ids 222,223,224 and 225 being problematic. As IDs are different for each store it would currently not be possible for any one to guess what the issue might be. I suggest taking a look at what these actual attributes are and then posting back here with the additional info.